# Passing a secured value from controller to model

Tags: php, yii, stripe-payments

I'm currently trying to pass a value (POST variable) from my Controller to my Model. This is a secured Stripe token, so it should not be stored anywhere, but I noticed it is.

Currently the token in stored in the db and then the Model accesses it in the beforeSave() function, to create the Stripe Charge object. I would like to create this object without storing the token, knowing that this token is passed in a POST variable.

I can access it easily in my Controller, but I'm not sure how to get it in my model.
I thought about creating customs function replacing the beforeSave one, and passing the token as an argument.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I used a public variable in my model, however I'm not sure if it's considered as stored ? Can someone enlighten me on this? Thanks!

Comment: Is it being persisted in a database with this approach? If not, then it isn't considered "stored" imo

Comment: It's not, I've run some tests and it seems to be ok. Thanks ;)